# How to get the specific child element from the parent in restconf

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-restconf

How to get the specific child element from the the parent in restconf, but at the same time to get all the parent's child in restconf?
**for example**:
my module

```
module system{
   leaf name{
      type string;
   }
   leaf version{
      type string;
   }
   container processors{
     list processor{
       key "id";
       leaf id{
         type string;
       }
       leaf name{
         type string;
       }
     }
   }
}
```

I want all the children of system(name, version, processors) but only the ids of processors :

```xml
<system>
  <name>system_1</name>
  <version>1</version>
  <processors>
   <processor>
     <id>1</id>
   </processor>
   <processor>
     <id>2</id>
   </processor>
  </processors>
</system>
```

what is the query that will invoke that answer in restconf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to have this by using the fields query parameter for the GET method.
Reference is available in RFC8040 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8040#section-4.8.3).

Request should be something like:

`GET /restconf/data?fields=(system:name;system:version;system:processors/processor/id)`

Note that you need to repeat the module name 'system' multiple times because you haven't defined a common top node in your example model.

Keep in mind that this works only if the RESTCONF server supports the 'fields' query parameter, which would need to be confirmed first.